# Playsms Vs Kannel as gateway

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, kannel

**Kannel is a compact and very powerful open source WAP and SMS gateway**

ALSO

**PlaySMS is a flexible Web-based Mobile Portal System that it can be made to fit to various services such as an SMS gateway,**

I am confused, if Playsms can serve as gateway, why we need kannel?

Comment: Jasmin is also: Open source, compact and powerful (from http://www.jasminsms.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Playsms and Kannel are not comparable, they are complementary; Playsms is a web portal to create and manage sms services on top of "compact" gateways, it is where Kannel is playing, but playsms is compatible with many other types of gateways.

It really depends on what you need to do:

1. Create a top-level messaging service ? then it is playsms ([more info](http://playsms.org/about/))
2. Use a gateway as a component for your own app ? web site ? ... then it is [kannel](http://www.kannel.org/), or [jasmin](http://www.jasminsms.com/), or [gnokii](http://www.gnokii.org/), or [gammu](http://wammu.eu/gammu/) ... (depends on your taste)

Comment: Late to the party but what exactly do you mean by "top-level"?